# How to parse dateTime "MM:SS-MM:SS" In R

Tags: r, datetime

I'm on a challenge learning R on Rstudio. And, as most of you, I found a lot of 'easy' look task that moving it into practice, it can become a little harder.

This is my actual issue:

I have a column with the time it happened (with 15' interval).

It looks likes :

```
  00:00-00:14 
  00:15-00:29 
  00:30-00:44
```

And so on. They look pretty right when I plot it, but I can't figure out how to solve f(x) of a predictive model.

**So my question is** : How can I parse it to quantifiable data? 
Should I change data structure? Is there a library that can show on plot '15 minutes intervals' and show up what interval is it ?

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of what you want to achieve. But if it is nicely in order and regularly spaced like this you could simply make it a factor, and then convert it to numeric to use as a continuous predictor in your model.

Comment: You'll probably need to decide on when your 15 min interval series starts from and then you can use lubridate library and generate a sequence `seq(ymd_hms('2014-01-21 00:00:00'),by = '15 min',length.out=(60*24*365/15))` (that's if you want a date value in your series) if you don't, you could use hms('00:00:00')